# dynamically embedding a surveymonkey survey into a div

Tags: javascript, python, html, surveymonkey

Let's say I made around 5 surveys on surveymonkey, and I am using a developer surveymonkey account to try and manipulate these surveys.

My end goal is to dynamically give them a survey based on what actions they took on a page. Let's just say for a brief example there are 5 buttons they can press, and on each, a new, different survey would appear in a sidebar or something along those lines

I can use [their API to return details of the surveys in my account](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/guide_first_request), but I can't seem to find a way to add a new collector or dynamically embed one of my surveys.

Is there a way to go about this?

Comment: well I tried using the surveyid, but it seems like the embed link is a link with much more information

Comment: I believe a feature request has already been logged to return the embed link in future, but it is not currently possible.  You may be able to iFrame the survey link into your site, but it's not something I've tried - retrieve the collectors for each survey using get_collector_list and make sure 'url' is passed through as a requested field.  Any web collectors will return that with a valid URL for that survey.

Also - you can't create collectors with the API yet, it's planned as a future feature though.